# IE6 flickers on enable/disable text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-6

I am using following two innocent lines of jQuery in my code

```
jQuery("#textfield").attr("disabled","disabled");

jQuery("#textfield").removeAttr("disabled");
```

just to enable and disable a text field. Whenever it happens, IE6 flickers the screen a bit. Is there any workaround for old rascal, IE6?

Comment: Is there a valid reason to support IE6?

Answer (score 0):

tried this ?

```
if($('#textfield').is(':disabled')){
    $('#textfield').prop('disabled',false);
}else{
    $('#textfield').prop('disabled',true);
}
```

Comment: I am already enabling and disabling field based on some condition. The problem is when field is enabled from disabled state or disabled from enabled state, IE screen flickers for a fraction of second.